# What are the files in the /Library/Image Capture/TWAIN Data Sources/ and can they be removed?

Tags: printing, canon, macos

In preparation for macOS 10.15, I'm reviewing my list of installed applications and removing those that are 32-bit. On the list of apps [identified by System Report](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/289196/64937), I see two things that are 32-bit:

- Canon MP530.ds
- Canon MP600.ds

Both of them reside in `/Library/Image Capture/TWAIN Data Sources/`, and they are the only contents of the folder.

These look like printers, but I have no idea if I ever installed those models. The "Last Modified" dates are nearly a decade ago. What are these files for, and is it safe to remove them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MP500 and [MP600](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/support-inkjet-printer/mp-series/pixma-mp600) are Canon all-in-one printer/scanners.

TWAIN is a driver protocol for [exchanging information with scanners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TWAIN).

[MPXXX.ds](https://support.usa.canon.com/kb/index?page=content&id=ART125524&cat=MAC_OS_X_10.7&actp=LIST) files are Canon drivers for the scanner component of these AIO printers.  Canon documentation indicates they can be removed by opening "Library, Image Capture, and TWAIN Data Sources, and move Canon MPXXX.ds to the trash", "if the MP Navigator or the MP drivers are no longer required."

Given the age of the MP600, unless you're still actively using one of these printers, the drivers should be safe to remove.

Comment: So were these third-party installations from me using the printers in the past? They didn't come from Apple, and so I can delete them if I no longer use those printers?

Comment: @Thunderforge yes.  if you don't have those printers anymore, there is no particular reason to have their scanner drivers lying around

Answer (score 0):

You can use time machine or another backup just in case, then remove these. Image Capture can import from scanners, so those would support some canon devices.

- https://www.twain.org/about/

If Apple installed them, you’ll likely get updates when needed and unless you get a problem with a scanner and can’t find newer drivers, you’ll have your backup.