# How easy is it to reinstall MacOS and change my disk setup?

Tags: macos, mac

I have a 2012 MacMini running Mojave. Originally MacOS was on the built-in 1Tb HDD but I got an external SSD and set this up as the main drive for OS, applications, etc. Given the Mac will no longer boot without the external drive, I believe I must have removed the original OS from the internal drive.

I would like to revert to booting from the internal drive, in a way that causes as little disruption as possible. Ideally I would be able to move installed apps rather than lose them, and certainly not have to format the drive. The external drive would be removed or become just a data drive.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Please add what exact stability issues you are having. It may or may not be the fault of the external drive. Also no Mac in 2012 came with a 1GB drive. That is **TINY** macOS won't even fit in 1GB. Edit your question with the correct size of your HD.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking, it's background information only

Comment: Then clarify your question, remove the noise and correct the issues.

Comment: Done. Hope you can help now

Comment: Is your internal drive big enough for all data stored in the external drive?

Answer (score 1):

1. Install to the internal using [erase install steps](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367355/want-to-delete-ubuntu-18-04-lts-from-macbook-air-2017-model).
2. Migrate data / apps / settings from the external using the [migration assistant](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/365596/finding-out-if-upgrading-to-a-newer-macos-version-will-cause-issues) portion of the os setup assistant.