# Can I use Steam in macOS Catalina or am I stuffed?

Tags: catalina, steam

There is a lot of conflicting information online about being able to use Steam in MacOS Catalina.

Can someone confirm if Steam will work on Catalina and if so what I must do to get it to work?

Or must I stay on Mojave to keep playing my games?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Steam will run fine in macOS Catalina.

However, what you may find is that it doesn’t launch initially. If this is the case, totally remove it from your system and then reinstall it from [Steam’s website](https://store.steampowered.com/about/) after you’re on macOS Catalina. This will ensure that the correct (i.e. 64-bit) version of Steam is installed for macOS.

**IMPORTANT**

**The fact that Steam itself runs fine does not guarantee that all of the games in your library will run fine.** So you will need to do your own due diligence to ensure your favourite games are compatible (i.e. they will need to be 64-bit versions to run on MacOS Catalina).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Is there a list anywhere of which games are compatible with on Catalina?

Comment: I have seen some user-compiled lists (mostly by Catalina Beta testers), but these aren't exhaustive. You may be able to check the RoaringApps site (see this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/365607/168832) for more info). However, your best bet is to contact the game developers directly - that way you can determine what their intentions are moving forward if their games aren't yet 64-bit.