# Does Catalina detect and warn about incompatible apps?

Tags: macos, catalina, 32-bit

I've been putting off upgrading from Mojave 10.14 to Catalina as I know I have at least one paid-for 32-bit app which doesn't offer a free upgrade.

This question talks about manually detecting 32-bit apps prior to installation: [How can I find out which Mac apps are 32-bit?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/289195/how-can-i-find-out-which-mac-apps-are-32-bit)

But I wondered, when Catalina is installed will it check for such apps and warn me they won't be usable? Further, will it tidy up by removing such apps or will I end up with non-runnable apps to manually clean up?

Answer (score 3):

32-bit apps in Mojave should already bring up a warning when you launch them.

You can check what 32-bit apps you have in System Information: Click to open the **Apple menu**, then hold <kbd>Option</kbd> and click on **System Information**, which appears where '**About This Mac**' was.

Then choose '**Applications**' from the sidebar, under **Software**. This will show you whether the app is 64-bit or not. You can sort the list by that column, giving you all the apps in one place.

[image]

Catalina will not remove any apps: it will just leave them in place.

Comment: How does MacOS _know_ what applications are installed since there's no Windows-style registry, does it just look at everything in the Applications directory or is there more to it?

Comment: @Mr.Boy iirc there are hidden files - which can (could) be updated when using cmnd-option-p-r which keep track of all sorts of information like which programs open which files etc

Comment: You can get to the same place by taking System Report after clicking About this Mac and selecting applications. Does not seem to show information for **all** the installed apps though.

Comment: @Mr.Boy You'll notice it takes a short time for the app to collate the information. It's mostly using Spotlight: there is a metadata field for the executable's architectures.